# Cypress : returns undefined on calling function from objects class in page object model

Tags: cypress

I am following page page object model in cypress. So get the value from `getName()` created object on class `MHome` and call the function `getName()` but it returns `undefined`

Object class

```
Class MHome{
    const loc = locator-A
    const loc1 = locator-B
     getName(){ 
         cy.getTeam2Home(loc, loc1).then((value)=>{
            // cy.log(value.toString())
             cy.wrap  (value.toString());
         })
    }
}
```

Calling the getName () function in cypress test case:

```
const Sh = new MHome();
And ("verify title of elements, function (){
  cy.log (Sh.get.Name())
})
```

`cy.log (Sh.get.Name())` returns `undefined` . Kindly help me in

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a lot of typos all around, a proper ts syntax would be:

```
class MHome {
    loc:string
    loc1: string
    constructor() {
        this.loc = "locator-A"
        this.loc1 = "locator-B"
    }
    getName() {
        return cy.getTeam2Home(this.loc, this.loc1).then((value)=>{
            // cy.log(value.toString())
            cy.wrap(value.toString());
        })
    }
}
```

And the instantiate the class and call the method like:

```
const Sh = new MHome()
Sh.getName().then((value)=> { cy.log(value) }
```

Comment: `Sh.getName()` shows `void` as return type even after after specifying `return` in `getName()` method. Please what is mistake ?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys your comments help me lot, problem sloved by using `cypress.promise` commands :

```
Class MHome{
    const loc = locator-A
    const loc1 = locator-B

     getName(){ 
       return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         cy.getTeam2Home(loc, loc1).then((value)=>{
            // cy.log(value.toString())
             resolve(value.toString());
         })
    }
}
```

And callig functions :

```
const Sh = new MHome();
And ("verify title of elements, function (){
  Sh.getName().then((val)=>{
            cy.log(val+'----ddd---');
        })
})
```